# React native make child component's z-index higher than parent's sibling

Tags: css, ios, reactjs, react-native, z-index

I have a few buttons arranged around a parent and child component. Problem is due to the way they are positioned not all the buttons are clickable. I tried playing with the zindex but that did not help.

Here is a code example of the problem. Only one of the buttons is clickable. How do I get them both to respond?

https://snack.expo.dev/KzHEQ_R0l